# Font Awesome, вопрос по вставке иконок

Tags: html, ttf, fontawesome

В общем в использовании Font Awesome пошел немного иным путем:
Взял  fontawesome-webfont.ttf и подключил его в css

```
@font-face {
font-family: fontawesome;
src: local(fontawesome), url(/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf);
```

}

соответственно освободился от длинной и не нужной портянки родных стилей шрифта, и лишней разметки в html, с использование ненужного `<i>` и пресущих ему классов. 
Ну а дальше как и в родных стилях через псевдоэлемент вывожу нужную мне иконку.
А как быть если я хочу вывести иконку в инпуте?

```
<input class="search-button" type="submit" value="чего здесь писать?">
```

Я так понимаю нужет html код иконки, но как его узнать?
Может даст кто совет как поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать

```
<button type="submit" value="Мое значение"><i class="fa fa-blabla></i> Мой текст</button>
```

Comment: Не совсем то что мне нужно, я не хочу использовать заводские классы шрифта..... Меня интерисует возможность вставки Html кода иконки

Comment: Так это оно и есть. Я вставил просто дефолтные. Тэг button тем и хорош, что он разделен на открывающий и закрывающий. Между ними можно вставить любой html с любой разметкой

Comment: Ну так ты используешь <i> с классами... тем самым нужно подключать заводскую таблицу стилей.... мне же этого не нужно...
меня интересует возможность  узнать Html код картинки в самом шрифте типо `&nbsp;` для пробела.

Comment: Не выйдет. Все равно надо будет вставить псевдоэлемент либо для ВСЕГО родительского элемента создать стиль с использованием фонт-шрифта. Если последний вариант устраивает, то переводим коды иконок в десятичную систему и выводим как &#123456; Коды unicode можно посмотреть, открыв ttf в винде